# Limiting query results to top 10 in mysql

Tags: mysql, loops

I'm trying to limit the following query results to only the top 10 responses.  So far the query does exactly what I want - namely it provides a list of the top systems, by count, ordered in descending order.  I get all 31 responses, but I only want the top 10 responses.  I've tried creating a While Do/End While loop, but I can't figure out exactly where to place it in the following code:

```
$sql = "
SELECT HelpDesk
     , COUNT(*) as NumSys 
  FROM `systems_17-18` 
 WHERE HelpDesk <>'' 
   AND HelpDesk <> 'NONE'    
 GROUP BY HelpDesk 
 ORDER 
    by NumSys DESC
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$mycount = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
echo "<table class='uk-table uk-table-condensed uk-table-hover uk-table-striped'>";        
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
$mycount ++;

echo "<tr>" ;
    echo "<td>";

    echo "<a href=" . $row['webaddress'] . " >";
    echo $row['SchoolDistrict'] . "</a>";
    echo "</td><td># " . $mycount . " " . $row['HelpDesk'] . " used by " .  $row[NumSys] . " district(s)";
echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
}
```

(NOTE: The code above correctly generates the data below.  But how would I limit the list to only the top 10 responses?  With a While EndWhile loop?)

School Districts in California that use Various Help Desk Systems:

```
 1 MyTechDesk used by 52 district(s)
 2 SchoolDude used by 40 district(s)
 3 WebHelpDesk used by 29 district(s)
 4 ZenDesk used by 15 district(s)
 5 SpiceWorks used by 14 district(s)
 6 KACE1000/2000 used by 13 district(s)
 7 FreshDesk used by 8 district(s)
 8 Track-IT! used by 6 district(s)
 9 Custom used by 6 district(s)
10 HEAT (Help Desk) used by 6 district(s)
11 SysAid used by 5 district(s)
12 ServiceDeskPlus used by 4 district(s)
13 GroupLink HelpDesk used by 4 district(s)
14 Altiris used by 4 district(s)
15 GLPI used by 3 district(s)
16 HESK used by 3 district(s)
17 HelpDesk used by 2 district(s)
18 Cherwell used by 2 district(s)
19 OPRAS used by 2 district(s)
20 Manage Engine Service Desk used by 2 district(s)
21 Samanage used by 1 district(s)
22 Absolute used by 1 district(s)
23 OTRS used by 1 district(s)
24 SherpaDesk used by 1 district(s)
25 Applied HelpDesk used by 1 district(s)
26 Public School Works used by 1 district(s)
27 iTop used by 1 district(s)
28 Connectwise used by 1 district(s)
29 Asana used by 1 district(s)
30 RT/SRTS used by 1 district(s)
31 OSTicket used by 1 district(s)
```

Comment: Have you considered using [MySQL LIMIT clause](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx).

Comment: There are a ton of questions that show how to do this, this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: For the future, consider searching for something like ["top 10 result in mysql"](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp). For anything you know how to do in MS SQL google how X in MySQL

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't bother with LIMIT on such a small result. Instead I would let PHP parse the entire result to an array and then output only the first 10 items of that array. Also, I'm not convinced that 'used by' and 'districts' aid readability!

Comment: I agree with your comment about "used by" and "districts" not aiding the readability.  I'll adjust that in the final output.  Thanks Strawberry.

Answer (score 1):

Add `LIMIT 10` after your `ORDER BY` statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT HelpDesk, COUNT(*) as NumSys FROM `schoolt7_systems`.`systems_17-18` WHERE HelpDesk <>'' AND HelpDesk <> 'NONE'     GROUP BY HelpDesk ORDER by NumSys DESC LIMIT 10";
```

EDIT: Changed from MS SQL Server to MySQL

REFERENCE: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Sorry for the duplicate entry.  I really did try and search for an answer before posting!

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT
    HelpDesk,
    COUNT(*) AS NumSys
FROM `schoolt7_systems`.`systems_17-18`
WHERE
    HelpDesk <>'' AND
    HelpDesk <> 'NONE'
GROUP BY   
     HelpDesk
ORDER by NumSys DESC
LIMIT 10               -- add this to your query
```